# Deleting cookies doesn't work with Webview2

Tags: c#, wpf, cookies, webview2

I'm trying to create an app to follow new chapters from my favorite website and get an alert when a new one is online.
The website is limited to 10 chapter and, in a regulat browser, deleting the cookies is enouth to be "a new guest" :

[image: photo1]

I use a Webview2 component (C# WPF) and the following code is not working :

```
    <Wpf:WebView2 Source="https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/return-of-the-disaster-class-hero/rdch-chapter-1" x:Name="wbv2Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500"/>
    <Button Content="Delete cookies" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          wbv2Test.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.DeleteAllCookies();
    }
```

I can spam the button, click once after each chapter displayed, this is always the limitation at the 11th chapter.
If I try with google chrome, this is enouth to remove the limitation :
[image: photo2]

I even try to create a new webview2 object but it doesn't change anything :

```
wbv2Test?.Dispose();
wbv2Test = new WebView2();
[...]
```

I have no idea why it doesn't working...

Comment: Have you tried: `wbv2Test.CoreWebView2.Reload()`  right after you delete the cookies?

Comment: I tried, the usual website message "accept cookies privacy stuff" is displayed again but the 10 chapter remains...